# AEM plugin is not available in eclipse marketplace

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aem

I am trying to add AEM plugin in eclipse but it is not available in eclipse marketplace

[image]

Current eclipse version - Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0). I want to install the AEM plugin in eclipse but I am not sure why it is not working in the current version. Is there anything else I need to add to make this work?

**[UPDATE]**
I get below error when manually trying to install using "Install New Software"

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AEM Developer Tools 1.3.0 (com.adobe.granite.ide.feature.feature.group 1.3.0)
  Missing requirement: Sling IDE Eclipse Core 1.2.2 (org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse-core 1.2.2) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.equinox.ds 1.2.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AEM IDE Tools: UI-Extensions 1.3.0 (com.adobe.granite.ide.eclipse-ui 1.3.0)
    To: osgi.bundle; org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse-core [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AEM Developer Tools 1.3.0 (com.adobe.granite.ide.feature.feature.group 1.3.0)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.adobe.granite.ide.eclipse-ui [1.3.0,1.3.0]
```

Comment: Yes, it is not listed in the Eclipse Marketplace. You might ask Adobe to do so. See here, how to install it manually: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/devtools/aem-eclipse.html?lang=en#how-to-install-the-aem-developer-tools-for-eclipse

Comment: I tried this before. The problem with manual approach is, https://eclipse.adobe.com/, there is no link to copy.

Comment: [`https://eclipse.adobe.com/`](https://eclipse.adobe.com/) is the update site, but also a web site. See my answer below.

Comment: The plugin is outdated. You may try to build it from source code which is available.

Comment: okay, is there any doc on how to build it from source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, AEM Developer Tools is not listed in the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/). You might ask Adobe to do so.

But you can **manually install *AEM Developer Tools* via the update site [`https://eclipse.adobe.com/`](https://eclipse.adobe.com/)**, following the [instructions here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/devtools/aem-eclipse.html?lang=en#how-to-install-the-aem-developer-tools-for-eclipse).

According to your update, the error when trying to install manually:

The required plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.equinox.ds` has been removed in the 2022-12 release. In the **preferences *Install/Update > Available Software Sites*** add the update site **[`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/)** and try again. With this, installation of *AEM Developer Tools* 1.3 should work. If you run into problems running it, you might want to use Eclipse 2022-09 as a workaround until *AEM Developer Tools* has been adapted for Eclipse 2022-12.

Comment: I get error while installing software manually. Seems like there is some problem AEM plugin in eclipse

Comment: If something is missing, it might be possible to fix it by adding another update site. Or maybe your Eclipse is too old or new for AEM. Which Eclipse IDE package of which version do you have and what error message do you get?

Comment: Current eclipse version - Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0). Updated the error message on original question. Could you please refer above?

Comment: See my updated answer according your update.

Comment: Thanks for providing more details. I get the same error even after executing your https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12/ in "Available Software Sites". I tried to restart eclipse after adding it but it did not help. Should I do anything else after adding https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12/ in Available Software Sites?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the [`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/`](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/) update site, not 2022-12 which is currently the latest release (see my corrected answer). In 2022-12 the required plugin does not exist anymore, so an update site is required containing the required plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I get the same error even after updating 2022-09 update.

Comment: What do you mean by _"after updating 2022-09 update"_? Did you add the update site `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/` in the preferences _ Install/Update > Available Software Sites_? For me, this works (I verified the solution in Eclipse 2022-12).

Comment: Holy smokes thank you, been hanging my head on this for a couple of days!  Confirmed fixed my issues on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 and Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0).  Added this to Eclipse > Settings > Install/Update > Available Software Sites:

Name: 2022-09
Location: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-09/